# Module naming overlaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, syntax

I'm using `Tkinter` with a GUI using a button inside the root window.
I also want to use a `Button` inside a `MatplotLib` graph that allows me to exit the graph (and potentially for other uses in the future).
The only problem is that they both use the same label `Button`. These two labels have different syntax so I can only either have `Tkinter` buttons or `Matplotlib` buttons.

I'm sure this is a very amateur question but is there a way to specify that this `Button` is a `tkinter` button while another `Button` is a `matplotlib` button?

Here's an example of the code:

```py
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

from tkinter import *

btn = Button(root, text="Plot", command=graph).pack()
```

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use wildcard imports.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer but this might be helpful to some people

You can instead use

import tkinter as tk

and then everytime you want to you a tkinter function you specify it by writing "tk." before it.

E.g.:
tk.Button
in this case and it will specifically use the tkinter version of the Button